# Algorithm for GCD of univariate polynomials, with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I need a fast algorithm for finding the GCD of several univariate polynomials, all with integer coefficients. Those polynomials vary according to input data in a program of mine. But generally their degree can be pretty big (>15 or much more, depending on input values to my program). There seems to be a mess over the web as to which algorithms are the fastest, and furthermore, my problem has the strong condition of integer coefficients, so maybe this makes things easier for algorithms. Unfortunately I cannot find such an algorithm (that takes into account the integer-ness of coefficients). So, I need your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the polynomials normed? How large are the coefficients? How many polynomials? Degree 15 is not that much, how much more? 50, 500, 50000).

Comment: @quid, no they are not normed. The coefficients can be in the range of 00's. Many polynomials (hundreds or thousands even). Degree, say, hundreds or thousands. This goes for 'hard' cases in input data. But of course I would start feeding the program with little values, first

Comment: I guess you can assume the coefficient of biggest term is 1

Comment: I do not understand your second comment. Why can I assume this when they are not normed?

Comment: @quid, I thought by 'normed' you meant sth statistical like norm = 1, so I have to confess I don't know what this term is. The polynomials come out of a combinatorial manipulation, which is sth really complicated to explain, but nothing special is done on them, so, what ever "normed" is, probably they are not. And yes the coef of largest degree term is 1

Comment: I guess the right classification would be monic polynomials with integer coefficients...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It seems normed is not a common term for this in English though. Sorry for the confusion. If they are monic, I think I'd just go with Euclidean algorithm. Anyway there ought to be good implementations for this around. If you do not have a very special use case or need I think you'll be fine with existing code/programs.

Comment: No, because: a) the Euclidean algorithm has been around for ages, so there has to be a much better set of tools to find GCD of polynomials. b) from my search, I got the impression that huge intermediate results (with more than 20 digits!) arise even for  small initial values fed to the Euclidean algorithm. I would consider this of course but only as a last resort

Comment: A thing that can play a role is if your polynomials are "dense" or have many zero coefficients; or some other special structure. You can look at  what is done in http://www.flintlib.org/ The express purpose of this library is to do such things fast.

Comment: The above remark regarding the relevance of "monic" was slightly off. I mentally mixed up something. FLINT appears to use the subresultant algorithm as descibed in Cohen's text on computational NT.

Comment: @quid I ll check that. Meanwhile I may find sth in R cran software...